# excel function or macro to split a column to rows

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I would like to split a column to a new columns as followed:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/azZM1.png

As you can see the split takes place whan there's a all text cell, and between those cells I don't always have the same number of cells.
Can I do that in a function or macro?

Comment: I don't think that I explained myself as good as I though. I have a column of over 6700+ cells and I want to split it to different column every time there's a cell with all text inside it (without numbers).

Answer (score 0):

This code takes your single column and breaks it up into multiple columns at each text header.

Assumptions:

- The left character of each non-header cell is a number.

  ```
  lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  frst = 1
  j = 2

  For i = 2 To lastRow + 1
      If Not IsNumeric(Left(Cells(i, 1).Value, 1)) Then
          Range(Cells(frst, 1), Cells(i - 1, 1)).Copy
          Range(Cells(1, j), Cells(i - frst - 1, j)).PasteSpecial

          frst = i
          j = j + 1
      End If
  Next i
  ```